# form onsubmit dynamically attach for validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to add onsubmit event dynamically using

```
if (window.addEventListener){   
    window.addEventListener('load', attachFormSubmit, false); 
} else if (window.attachEvent){ 
    window.attachEvent('onload', attachFormSubmit );
}
```

but if you see the example on this URL http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

it says.

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" />
```

the return statement, how can this work with dynamic assignment.

EDIT..

my question is about the inline call inside onsubmit with a return statement, can we do this dynamically inside of hard coding it "return validateForm()" inside the onsubmit handler?

Comment: I would probably just avoid that site (Note that [w3c](http://www.w3.org/) and w3schools are not in any way connected). Check this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Comment: Isn't it easier to find a fallback for [HTML5 form validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to write the `attachFormSubmit` function?

Comment: @barmar <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" />, see, the function call is inline with a return statement inside onsubmit so it returns true/false to form onsubmit attribute, how can we do the same dynamically

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree"/>
    <label for="agree">I agree to the TOS.</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

If you've already found a good cross-browser DOMContentLoaded/onload implementation, assume `init()` runs at the start.

```
function validateForm(evt) {
    if(!document.getElementById('agree').checked) {
    //  W3C spec
        if(evt.preventDefault)
            { evt.preventDefault(); }
    //  IE < 9
        else if(evt.returnValue)
            { evt.returnValue = false; }
    //  catch-all
        return false;
    }
}
function init() {
    var myForm = document.getElementById('myform');

//  W3C spec
    if(myForm.addEventListener)
        { myForm.addEventListener('submit',validateForm,false); }
//  IE < 9
    else if(myForm.attachEvent)
        { myForm.attachEvent('onsubmit',validateForm); }
//  catch-all
    else
        { myForm.onsubmit = validateForm; }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not looking for a cross browser implementation, please see the comment under my question for barmer, the inline function with a return statement, we can't attach a function dynamically to a form, can we?

Comment: If you don't utterly lack the ability to use unobtrusive code, there is no reason not to. Aside from that just pick and choose which parts from the above you need.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an ID, and then do:

```
document.getElementById("formId").onsubmit = validateForm;
```

Comment: function validateForm() {
 return false; 
}
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = validateForm; //the form still gets submitted

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ZBtmB/6/. Make sure you're doing the assignment after the DOM is loaded, either at the bottom of the HTML or in the `window.onload` function.